# how to add NSDictionary data to NSMutable Array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I am trying to add aDict data to myData(NSMutable Array), but am not able to add it. whenever I am trying to print it(myData). It is printing null.

```
for ( NSDictionary *aDict in responseArray){
    NSLog(@"%@", aDict[@"brand"]);
    myData[count]=aDict[@"brand"];
 }
 NSLog(@"%@",myData[2]);
```

My data is in the format

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "brand": "AMANTE",
        "brand_id": 216,
        "size": "XL",
        "size_id": 78,
        "url_path": "brands-1.html?brand=216&size=78"
    },
    {
        "brand": "PENNY",
        "brand_id": 1349,
        "size": "LARGE",
        "size_id": 54,
        "url_path": "brands-1.html?brand=1349&size=54"
    },
    {
        "brand": "TRIUMPH",
        "brand_id": 58,
        "size": "LARGE",
        "size_id": 54,
        "url_path": "brands-1.html?brand=58&size=54"
    },
    {
        "brand": "BENETTON",
        "brand_id": 2519,
        "size": "LARGE",
        "size_id": 54,
        "url_path": "brands-1.html?brand=2519&size=54"
    },
    {
        "brand": "HANES",
        "brand_id": 446,
        "size": "LARGE",
        "size_id": 54,
        "url_path": "brands-1.html?brand=446&size=54"
    },
    {
        "brand": "JOCKEY",
        "brand_id": 60,
        "size": "40B",
        "size_id": 76,
        "url_path": "brands-1.html?brand=60&size=76"
    },
    {
        "brand": "LOVABLE",
        "brand_id": 59,
        "size": "40B",
        "size_id": 76,
        "url_path": "brands-1.html?brand=59&size=76"
    },
    {
        "brand": "HANES",
        "brand_id": 446,
        "size": "40B",
        "size_id": 76,
        "url_path": "brands-1.html?brand=446&size=76"
    },
    {
        "brand": "ENAMOR",
        "brand_id": 56,
        "size": "40B",
        "size_id": 76,
        "url_path": "brands-1.html?brand=56&size=76"
    },
    {
        "brand": "BIARA",
        "brand_id": 2480,
        "size": "40B",
        "size_id": 76,
        "url_path": "brands-1.html?brand=2480&size=76"
    },
    {
        "brand": "PENNY",
        "brand_id": 1349,
        "size": "40B",
        "size_id": 76,
        "url_path": "brands-1.html?brand=1349&size=76"
    },
    {
        "brand": "TRIUMPH",
        "brand_id": 58,
        "size": "40B",
        "size_id": 76,
        "url_path": "brands-1.html?brand=58&size=76"
    },
    {
        "brand": "LIBERTINA",
        "brand_id": 4167,
        "size": "40B",
        "size_id": 76,
        "url_path": "brands-1.html?brand=4167&size=76"
    },
    {
        "brand": "INNER SENSE",
        "brand_id": 3685,
        "size": "40B",
        "size_id": 76,
        "url_path": "brands-1.html?brand=3685&size=76"
    },
    {
        "brand": "ANITA",
        "brand_id": 3919,
        "size": "40B",
        "size_id": 76,
        "url_path": "brands-1.html?brand=3919&size=76"
    },
    {
        "brand": "ADIRA",
        "brand_id": 2584,
        "size": "40B",
        "size_id": 76,
        "url_path": "brands-1.html?brand=2584&size=76"
    },
    {
        "brand": "COUCOU",
        "brand_id": 2008,
        "size": "40B",
        "size_id": 76,
        "url_path": "brands-1.html?brand=2008&size=76"
    },
    {
        "brand": "362436",
        "brand_id": 2119,
        "size": "XL",
        "size_id": 78,
        "url_path": "brands-1.html?brand=2119&size=78"
    }
],
"status": "success"
}
```

I want only "brand" in my NSMutable Array *myData.

Comment: `for (NSDictionary *aDict in responseDictionary["data"]) { ... }`, as you have a root object which you just ignore, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Try like: if your array of dictionary contains key `data`, you can access directly:

```
NSMutableArray *addarra = [NSMutableArray new];

for ( NSDictionary *aDict in responseArray){
   NSMutableDictionary *temp = [NSMutableDictionary new];
  [temp setObject:aDict[@"brand"] forKey:@"brand"];
   [addarra addobject:temp];

}
```

Retrieve:

```
NSString *brand  = [[addarra objectAtIndex:i]ObjectForKey:@"brand"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If the print result is null, it means that you didn't create the "mydata" NSMutableArray. Here is my code.

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"data":@[
                                   @{
                                       @"brand": @"AsafdsadfsdANTE",
                                       @"brand_id": @216,
                                       @"size": @"XL",
                                       @"size_id": @78,
                                       @"url_path": @"brands-1.html?brand=216&size=78"
                                       },@{
                                       @"brand": @"UYTIT",
                                       @"brand_id": @216,
                                       @"size": @"XL",
                                       @"size_id": @78,
                                       @"url_path": @"brands-1.html?brand=216&size=78"
                                       },@{
                                       @"brand": @"sFASDSADF",
                                       @"brand_id": @216,
                                       @"size": @"XL",
                                       @"size_id": @78,
                                       @"url_path": @"brands-1.html?brand=216&size=78"
                                       },@{
                                       @"brand": @"GERWW",
                                       @"brand_id": @216,
                                       @"size": @"XL",
                                       @"size_id": @78,
                                       @"url_path": @"brands-1.html?brand=216&size=78"
                                       },

                                   ],
                           @"status":@"success"

                           };
    NSMutableArray *myData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C", nil];
    NSArray *data = dict[@"data"];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in data) {
        NSString *brand = dict[@"brand"];
        NSLog(@"%@",brand);
        [myData addObject:brand];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",myData);
```

Answer (score 1):

## list of the `brand` values

the easiest way is:

```
NSArray *_brands = [responseArray[@"data"] valueForKeyPath:@"brand"];
```

that will gives you an array which has all values, but one *brand* can be multiple times in the final collection, so if the e.g. `TRIUMPH` brands are two times in your original data source, that will be two times in the `_brands` array as well.

---

## every `brand` value only once

you can do this:

```
NSArray *_brands = [[NSSet setWithArray:[responseArray[@"data"] valueForKeyPath:@"brand"]] allObjects];
```

or even that:

```
NSArray *_brands = [responseArray[@"data"] valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.brand"];
```

in both case, each *brand* will be only once in your `_brands` array like e.g. `TRIUMPH`, although it occurs two times it will be only once in the output collection, regardless how many times the data source has the same value; you can use whichever you'd prefer better or makes more sense to your project.

---

## mutable collection

if you need really a mutable collection at the end:

```
NSMutableArray *_mutableBrands = [_brands mutableCopy];
```